# std::function and function templates

Tags: c++, templates, std-function

I want to assign to a std::function a function defined through a function template, but I get unresolved overloaded function type errors

```cpp
// template
template <std::function<double(double)> &f, int i>
double iter(double x)
{
   for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
   {
      x=f(x);
   }
   return x;
}

// function
double poly(double x)
{
   return pow(x,2)-2;
}

int main()
{
   // I expect on the right the object iter to be of type
   // double(double), but the compiler says is unresolved function type
   std::function<double(double)> f= iter<poly, 2>;
   std::cout << f(1.0) <<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
template <std::function<double(double)> &f, int i>
double iter(double x)
```

The first parameter of this template function is a (reference to a) `std::function`. Ignoring a few other problems with this approach, the biggest issue is that:

```
iter<poly, 2>;
```

`poly` is not a `std::function`. It is a plain, garden-variety function. You can use a plain function pointer to construct a compatible `std::function`, but this is not constructing an instance of an object. We're working with template parameters here, which is not the same thing.

You can simply pass the callable object as a parameter to `iter()`, instead of using a template parameter. Like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

template<int i>
double iter(const std::function<double(double)> &f, double x)
{
   for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
   {
      x=f(x);
   }
   return x;
}

// function
double poly(double x)
{
   return pow(x,2)-2;
}

int main()
{
   std::function<double(double)> f=
       []
       (double v)
       {
           return iter<2>(poly, v);
       };

   std::cout << f(1.0) <<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

It is not clear if this was actually your intended calculation, but this is the general idea. Adjust as needed. Here, you're using `poly`, which is evaluated as a function pointer, to construct a `std::function`.

Comment: so, while the conversion of a plain function to std::function is implicit at runtime, the same is not true at compilation time?

Comment: The actual conversion is done at runtime, but it is a valid compile-time conversion, that's why it compiles. A parameter to a template instance has no equivalent compile-time conversions, here.

Answer (score 1):

Before C++20, the only allowed types for template parameters are:

- std::nullptr_t (since C++11);
- an integral type;
- a pointer type (to object or to function);
- a pointer to member type (to member object or to member function);
- an enumeration type.

Since `std::function<double(double)> &` is none of these, you cannot use it in your template parameter.

You can, however, use a pointer to a function which has external linkage, like this:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// template
template <double(*f)(double), int i>
double iter(double x)
{
   for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
   {
      x=f(x);
   }
   return x;
}

// function
double poly(double x)
{
   return std::pow(x,2)-2;
}

int main()
{
   // this compiles!
   std::function<double(double)> f= iter<poly, 2>;
   std::cout << f(1.0) <<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: On https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter, the list of allowed parameter types starts with `lvalue reference type (to object or to function);`, even before your sublist. Pointers are not different from references here.

Comment: @bipll `poly` is not a `lvalue`.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Sure, and its type is not `std::function`.